# React route working properly when used with <Link> but not working when redirected from webpack.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, react-router-dom

In my react project I am using client side routing using React Router DOM v4.

Video link to my problem statement: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nHY-dKxZvDylF5GQUTK02I8Mam1d5eru/view?usp=sharing

I have created the route like this `<Route path="/pg-response/:status" component={PaytmResponse} exact={true}/>`

**Here is my AppRouter.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

import HomePage from './../components/HomePage';
import AboutUs from './../components/AboutUs';
import ContactUs from './../components/ContactUs';
import PageNotFound from './../components/PageNotFound';
import RestaurantList from '../components/RestaurantList';
import Foodcourt from '../components/Foodcourt';
import RestaurantMenu from '../components/RestaurantMenu';
import UserDetails from '../components/UserDetails';
import OrderConfirmation from '../components/OrderConfirmation';
import CustomerAccount from '../components/CustomerAccount';
import Logout from '../components/sections/Logout';
import RedirectPG from '../components/sections/RedirectPG';
import SodexoResponse from '../components/sections/SodexoResponse';
import OrderFail from '../components/OrderFail';
import PaytmResponse from '../components/sections/PaytmResponse';


export default () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route render={({location}) => (
                <TransitionGroup>
                    <CSSTransition key={location.key} timeout={300} classNames="fade">
                        <Switch location={location}>
                            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true}/>
                            <Route path="/about" component={AboutUs} />
                            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactUs} />
                            <Route path="/restaurants" component={RestaurantList} />
                            <Route path="/foodcourt" component={Foodcourt} />
                            <Route path="/select-menu" component={RestaurantMenu} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/user-details" component={UserDetails} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/order-confirmation" component={OrderConfirmation} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/payment-failed" component={OrderFail} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/my-account" component={CustomerAccount} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/redirect-to-pg" component={RedirectPG} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/sodexo-response" component={SodexoResponse} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/paytm-response"/>
                            <Route path="/pg-response/:status" component={PaytmResponse} exact={true}/>

                            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                        </Switch>
                    </CSSTransition>
                </TransitionGroup>
            )} />

        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

**The problem is that when I go on this route from `<Link>` click it works without any problem. 
But when I go on this route by redirecting from `webpack.config.js` file I get a lot of errors.**

**Here is my webpack.config.js file**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const url = require('url');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const app = express();

module.exports = (env) => {

    const isProduction = env === 'production';
    const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

    return {
        entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/app.js'],
        output: {
            path : path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: CSSExtract.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 8000,
                                name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                                publicPath: '/dist/'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|mp4)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "file-loader",
                            options: {
                                name: 'files/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                                publicPath: '/dist/'
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            CSSExtract,
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                "window.jQuery": "jquery"
            })
        ],
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            historyApiFallback: true,
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            setup: (app) => {
                app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
                app.post('/paytm-response',(req, res) => {
                    res.redirect(`/pg-response/${req.body.STATUS}`);
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also using the `historyApiFallback: true`.
Still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searches, I found that inside the `index.html` file I was using the relative path to the scripts and CSS files.

I changed them to an absolute path and everything worked fine.

It was not the problem of web pack or anything else, just a problem with the way scripts and CSS files were imported in `index.html` file.